# Java file compile using javac unable to refer to other files in the same directory

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, javac

I am trying to migrate from IDEs like Eclipse to a standalone Java environment, but I'm having problems tying together multiple files into a project.

Here is some sample code, where both files are in the same directory:

**App.java**

```java
package com.example.main;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example.test();
    }
}
```

**Example.java**

```java
package com.example.main;

public class Example {
    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("It's working");
    }
}
```

When running `App.java` in an IDE, the expected output of `It's working` is printed, however after executing `javac *.java` the files seem to ignore eachother.

Here is the error that occurs when executing `java App.java` after it's been compiled:

```
App.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                Example.test();
                ^
  symbol:   variable Example
  location: class App
1 error
error: compilation failed
```

How can I compile the files in a project so that they recognise eachother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you running Java 11 and above, `java App.java` will compile `App.java` only.

If you need to refer `Example.java`, first you need to compile both java files into a directory.
Let give it named 'classes'. The command will be

`javac -d classes *.java`

After that, you can run it via

`java -cp classes com.example.main.App`. Please note that App is without `.class` suffix

Of course, it is advisable to use build tools like [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) to build your project if it grow larger or need other dependencies.